# Python Mouse clicker, can get mouse position but unable to recall it

Tags: python, mouse, pynput, pysimplegui

I'm stuck. This is a helper app for my coworkers to refresh a webpage by clicking on the refresh button. 
What doesn't work so far is grabbing the x,y coordinates (getx,gety) and the GUI locks up after F5 is pressed. I think the issue is when the function on_activate is called the x,y from pyautogui is not available outside the function. maybe? 
I had to add a function get_position because the listener was causing the GUI to never populate.

I'm still learning python so any help is appreciated. I feel like I'm so close but missing something.

```
"""
Created on Mon Dec 16 12:13:06 2019
Auto clicker for page refresh. Looks for hotkey to grab the mouse location, F5. The button GetPos must be pressed before F5 is available. Then Start Clicking can be pressed and the mouse should click on the x,y coordinates once per delay setting.
The Pause button will pause clicking.
"""
from pynput import keyboard
import pynput
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pyautogui
import time
i = 1
getx=None
gety=None
delay =None

#-------------Functions-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

def stop_clicking(): # for pause button
    pass

def on_activate(): # get click location
    print('Global hotkey activated!')
    getx, gety = pyautogui.position()
    positionStr = 'X: ' + str(getx).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(gety).rjust(4)
    print(positionStr)
    end_listener()
    return(getx,gety)

def end_listener(): # end keyboard listener, but does not work
    pynput.keyboard.Listener.stop
    print('end listener')

def ClickMouse(): # click mouse at location loop
    while (i < 20):
        time.sleep(delay)
        pyautogui.click(getx, gety)
        print('clicked'+ getx)

def get_position(): # keyboard listener for hotkey
    hotkey = keyboard.HotKey(
        keyboard.HotKey.parse('<f5>'),
        on_activate)
    with keyboard.Listener(
         on_press=hotkey.press,
        on_release=hotkey.release) as l:
        l.join()

# ----------------  Create PYSimpleGUI Form-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('LightBlue')
sg.SetOptions(element_padding=(0, 0))

layout = [[sg.Text('Press F5 to get the mouse position. ')],
          #[sg.Text('', size=(8, 2), font=('Helvetica', 20), justification='center', key='text')],
          [sg.Text('X: ' + str(getx).ljust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(gety).ljust(4), size=(10, 2), font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text2')],
          [sg.Text('Delay in Seconds ', font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text'),sg.InputText('', size=(3, 1), font=('Helvetica'), key='delay'), sg.Button('Submit',key='submit')],
          [sg.Text('', size=(8, 1), font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text3')],
          [sg.ReadButton('Pause', key='pause', button_color=('white', '#001480')),
           sg.ReadButton('Start Clicking', button_color=('white', '#007339'), key='Start'),
           sg.ReadButton('GetPos', button_color=('white', '#007339'), key='getPos'),
           sg.Exit(button_color=('white', 'firebrick4'), key='Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Refresher', layout, no_titlebar=True, auto_size_buttons=False, keep_on_top=True,
                   grab_anywhere=True)

getx,gety = on_activate() # works to get a getx and gety value but calls function to soon, duh
print(getx) # see if I get a value for getx (debuging)

keys_entered = 'X: ' + str(getx).ljust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(gety).ljust(4) #variable for window refresh below

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:  # X (close) on the window
        break
    elif event == 'submit':
        delay = values['delay']
    elif event == 'Pause':
        stop_clicking()
    elif event == 'Start':
        ClickMouse()
    elif event == 'Exit':
        exit
    elif event =='getPos':
        get_position()
    window['text2'].update(keys_entered)  # change the window to reflect current key string, so far does not work

window.close()
```

New code using wind32api to replace pyautogui.

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import time
import win32api
import win32con
import sys

i = 1
x=None
y=None
delay =None
paused = False

#-------------Functions----------------------------------------------------------

def stop_clicking(): # for pause button
    pass

def on_activate(): # get click location
    print('Global hotkey activated!')
    x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
    win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
    positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
    print(positionStr)
    time.sleep(2)

def where_is():
    print (x)
    print (y)

def ClickMouse(): # click mouse at location loop
    while True:
        win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
        time.sleep(.05)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, x, y, 0, 0)
        time.sleep(0.05)
        win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, x, y, 0, 0)
        print('clicked'+ x)
        time.sleep(4)

# ----------------  Create PYSimpleGUI Form--------------------------------------
sg.ChangeLookAndFeel('LightBlue')
sg.SetOptions(element_padding=(0, 0))

layout = [[sg.Text('After pressing Get Pos, Press F5 to get the mouse position. ')],
          #[sg.Text('', size=(8, 2), font=('Helvetica', 20), justification='center', key='text')],
          [sg.Text('X: ' + str(x).ljust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).ljust(4), size=(20, 1), font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text2')],
          [sg.Text('Delay in Seconds ', font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text'),sg.InputText('', size=(3, 1), font=('Helvetica'), pad=(2,0) , key='delay'), sg.Button('Submit',key='submit')],
          [sg.Text('', size=(8, 1), font=('Helvetica', 10), justification='center', key='text3')],
          [sg.ReadButton('Pause', key='pause', button_color=('white', '#001480')),
           sg.ReadButton('Start Clicking', button_color=('white', '#007339'), key='Start'),
           sg.ReadButton('Get Pos', key='getpos', button_color=('orange', 'black')),
           sg.Exit(button_color=('white', 'firebrick4'), key='Exit')]]

window = sg.Window('Refresher', layout, no_titlebar=True, auto_size_buttons=False, keep_on_top=True,
                   grab_anywhere=True)

keys_entered = 'X: ' + str(x).ljust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).ljust(4) #variable for window refresh below

while True:  # Event Loop
    event, values = window.read()
    if event is None:  # X (close) on the window
        break
    elif event == 'submit':
        delay = values['delay']
    elif event == 'Pause':
        paused =True
        element = window('start')
        element.update(text='Start Clicking')
        stop_clicking()
    elif event == 'Start':
        paused = False
        ClickMouse()
    elif event == 'Exit':
        sys.exit()


if win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x74):
             print('Global hotkey activated!')
             x, y = win32api.GetCursorPos()
             win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
             positionStr = 'X: ' + str(x).rjust(4) + ' Y: ' + str(y).rjust(4)
             print(positionStr)
             time.sleep(2)

window['text2'].update(keys_entered)  # change the window to reflect current key string, so far does not work

window.close()
```

Comment: What do you imagine `return(getx,gety)` does when called by `HotKey`?

Comment: That was an attempt to get the variables out of the function. But it would just send it to get_position/ hotkey if I understand it correctly, which would do nothing with it. from you question, then should I put in a container in hotkey to hold the variables getx and gety?

Comment: You have already chosen a container—the module object which holds `global` variables.

Comment: If getx and gety are actually global variables, what is preventing them from being read in the ClickMouse function and the window update? Seems like that is what I am missing.

Comment: You may be running into a problem where both PySimpleGUI and PyAutoGUI are blocking in their calls. I don't know the architecture of PyAutoGUI well enough.  If the GUI is "locked up" it means you're not calling the window.read method often enough... you may have read something and then went off never returning.  This will look like a lock-up.

Comment: @RobE: They’re being read fine, but nothing is assigning to them except your “too soon” line.

Comment: @DavisHerring Is there a creative way to get that 'too soon' line to wait until the keypress happens?

Comment: I tried using win32api to replace pyAutoGUI. same result, so it's clearly me.

Comment: @RobE: That’s not what needs fixing.  I tried to give a hint by formatting the word “global”…

Comment: @DavisHerring Then I need to add Global x,y to the function on_activate?

Comment: @RobE: Yes, or the equivalent in the older version with its variable names.